# how can i call up either part of the results like (e1,e5,e6,e9)or (from e1 to e7) in matlab? then i need to combine them in one array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

if i have a lot of arrays with different dimensions and their names take the following forms :e1,e2,e3,...,e10 and so on. how can i call up either part of the results like (e1,e5,e6,e9)or (from e1 to e7)? then i need to combine them in one array . for your information , these array names resulted from this code :

```
{clc
clear
a=input('please, select your array :')
b=a(:)'
c=length(b)
for d=1:c
    if (d<c)
      eval(sprintf('e%d = nchoosek(b,%d)', d,d))
    end
end}
```

what i need is, combine matrices like (e1,e2,e3,e4) vertically meaning that each matrix under other in one matrix not each element of all matrices under each other .
Notes:- empty cells do not include numbers will be produced resulting from the different sizes of the matrices when combining them ,then, i want to pad these cells with zeros

Comment: Notes:- i need to combine them vertically in one array

Comment: `e1,e2....` are matrices not arrays, and each of them are of different sizes, so what do you mean when you say " i need to combine them vertically in one array "

Comment: i mean that the final matrix will include _for example_ e1,e2,e3,e4 under each other and therefore will be empty cells of numbers in final matrix . what i need, is combine the matrices vertically (under each other) and pad the empty cells(resulting from combination operation)are padded and filled with zeros. Notes:- If there is anything unclear tell me and I will show more

Answer (score 4):

First off: Using `eval` for creating variable names is bad practice. I suggest you change your code to the following:

```
a = input('Please, select your array: ')
b = a(:).'
c = length(b)
for d =1:c
    if (d<c)
      e{d} = nchoosek(b, d);
    end
end
```

## Updated answer:

Following your comment:

You can use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to insert zeros so that all cells have the same number of columns. [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is used in order to do the same operations on each cell.

```
 cellfun(@(m) padarray(m,[0 max(cellfun(@(n) size(n,2), e)) - size(m,2)],'post'), e,'UniformOutput',0)

  Columns 1 through 5
    [7x6 double]    [21x6 double]    [35x6 double]    [35x6 double]    [21x6 double]
  Column 6
    [7x6 double]
```

Now all matrices have the same number of columns and you can combine them in any way you want, for instance using `cell2mat` like this.

```
cell2mat(x([1 3 5])')
```

## Original answer:

Now you say you want to combine all the matrices vertically. You can do this by combining [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) like this:

```
cell2mat(cellfun(@(n) n(:), e, 'UniformOutput',0)')
```

If you only want number 1 and 3 you can do:

```
cell2mat(cellfun(@(n) n(:), e([1 3]), 'UniformOutput',0)')
```

The `cellfun`-part is equivalent to:

```
k = 1;
for ii = [1 3]
   f{k} = e{ii}(:);
   k = k + 1;
end
```

`cell2mat` concatenates the cells vertically.

This does the same as if you wanted to align the two following vectors vertically:

```
a = [1 3; 2 4];
b = [5 8 11; 6 9 12; 7 10 13];
c = [a(:); b(:)]   
c =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
```

Comment: what i need is, combine matrices like (e1,e2,e3,e4) vertically meaning that each matrix under other in one matrix not each element of all matrices under each other . Notes:- empty cells do not include numbers will be produced resulting from the different sizes of the matrices when combining them ,then, i want to pad these cells with zeros

Comment: @user3735754 `cell2mat(x([1 3 5])')` line in this answer exactly does what you have asked in this comment, what else do you want ?

Comment: I am unable to thank you "peter" , that's what i want exactly  thank you very match my friend

Comment: @user3735754, I'm assuming I'm Peter? Glad I could help =) The best way to thank me is by checking the tick mark on the left side of the answer =)

Comment: i promise you , i will do

Comment: @user3735754, will you? :P